# Bitbucket, Windows and "fatal: could not read Password for"

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket

I recently reinstalled Windows and I have a problem with downloading files from repository.

I have installed GIT and Python, but when I am trying to download anything from Bitbucket I get the message:

```
"fatal: could not read Password for: 'https://username@bitbucket.org': No such file or directory".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this worked for me if you don't want to setup ssh http://stackoverflow.com/a/22169458/632027

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same problem an hour or so ago. My issue was that I was trying to do a git clone but using the https url instead of the ssh one. If you go to your repository you can select ssh or https from the dropdown for the clone url. Hope that helps!

Comment: Git bash has ssh in it although you don't need to use it directly. In git bash just do git clone <the ssh url for your repo>

Comment: I found this document useful as you might have to create an ssh key to allow the authentication https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

Comment: I followed the instructions there and still the same fatal error.

Comment: Make sure you are using the ssh url and not the https one http://imgur.com/y1dKKNu

Comment: I'm sure that I'm using correct url. I modified git config, so it uses the ssh one.

Answer (score 122):

I solved it setting a global parameter:

```
git config --global core.askpass /usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
```

Comment: This was very helpful on my PC, but I just installed git on my laptop (Win 8.1), and the command line asked me for the password with no need of your solution. Does anybody know why some installations don't need this solution?

Comment: @min.yong.yoon this appears to be a git version issue.  That might explain the difference you see

Comment: in my case git-core was just in usr/lib/

Comment: Thanks so much! If that command doesn't work, git-gui-askpass might be in a different location. I'm using cmder, so I ran this command: `git config --global core.askpass "C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\msysgit\libexe
c\git-core\git-gui--askpass"`

Comment: if you have x64 windows and installed "git for windows" than this might helps `git config --global core.askpass "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core\git-gui--askp
ass"`

Comment: I've got x64 git for windows and typed: `git config --global core.askpass "C:\Program Files\Git\\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-gui--askpass"`

Comment: open-ssh askpass works as well ```git config --global core.askpass /usr/bin/ssh-askpass```

Answer (score 70):

Try to include your username and password in the URL like this:

```
git clone https://username:password@bitbucket.org/path_to/myRepo.git
```

Comment: Instead of cloning again, you can also modify .git/config file to add your password into the url. However, it is not secure to leave your password in a plan config file though.

Comment: @SimonXinCheng Creating a SSH key and adding it to BitBucket is a really better solution than writing your password in plain text into the config file.

Comment: btw: not secure at all

Comment: Needed this for testing scripts on a container, throwaway use once scenario

Comment: modify the URL by menu: Git -> Manage Remotes -> edit the origin URL

Answer (score 12):

Just solved this Problem

Git in Version 1.8.5.2 contains a but using bitbucket, updating my Git to Version 1.9.0 solved this problem.

Comment: This also solved the issue for me. Upgraded from 1.8.5.2 to 1.9.4 (Windows 7 64bit)

Comment: Same for me. Windows7, 64bit, Upgraded from 1.8.5 to 1.9.4

Answer (score 9):

I just tried to do the same thing and it did not work for me, and I too recently reinstalled windows on my machine.

I am used to checking out a private repo from my bitbucket account by using the simple command 
   `git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git`
and then being prompted to enter a password for my user.

It looks like this might be broken in version 1.8.5.2. I downgraded to version 1.8.4 and it started working as expected.

Git download list: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 this described and fixed the issue for me too ... logging a bug on git site

Comment: +1 Thank you! If anyone is looking for the previous version, get it here: https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.8.4-preview20130916.exe&can=2&q=

Comment: I've created an [unofficial fix release (1.8.5.4)](https://github.com/nevik/git/releases/tag/v1.8.5.4.msysgit.nevik.0) for people who want to or need to use a Git version newer than 1.8.4. This should serve as an intermediate solution until a new official release is made.

Comment: Git for windows 1.9.0-preview20140217 is now out, and I confirmed that it fixes this issue.

Answer (score 4):

For https connections try installing the "Git Credential Store" (an "optional" step in the BitBucket tutorial).

This is how to install it:

1. Download git-credential-winstore.exe from http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/
2. Open the Git Bash Shell and change the current directory to where git-credential-winstore.exe is located
3. Run `./git-credential-winstore -i /bin/git`

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `git fetch` in order to reenter and update the outdated password.

I had the similar issue. The cached password become invalid due to updating the actual password to new one. But git didn't ask me for reentering the valid password and just gave me an error that `Authentication failed` while I was trying to pull changes.

But magically, git asked me for the actual password when I typed `git fetch` instead of pulling the data. Once I entered the new password, apparently git updated the old one in its credentials storage and no longer asked me about the entering password again.

Answer (score 4):

**FIX IT** (09/2020)

All the the answers here are wrong... You shouldn't NEVER do something like that:

https://username:**PASSWORD**@Bitbucket.org

**SOLUTION**
All you have to do is:

- Go to *Sourcetree -> Preferences -> Git*
- You will have the section "Git Version" with 2 options: *Reset to ebedded* Git and *Use System Git*

Sourcetree use the Ebedded git for default.
Click on "**Use System Git**" and.... Fixed!

---

Follow me on:
[GIthub](https://github.com/PierW)
[Twitter](https://twitter.com/pierpaolow)

Comment: Alternatively you can try updating the Embedded version. Either worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the `Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2` integrated version control. Additionally I have BitBucket and GitHub ssh keys setup on my Windows PC. I was able to fix the issue by setting checked `Use credential helper` in **File | Settings | Version Control | Git**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was with the global file `.gitconfig` on Windows.

When I tried to use [solution provided by @jsarroyo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376155/4568679) in *Git BASH*, I got an error saying that the file `.gitconfig.lock` did not exist. I could find no way to fix it.

When I completely removed `.gitconfig`, everything worked fine.

**WARNING:** This way, you lose all your git settings and you need to configure it again.

Answer (score 1):

In your project go to `.git/config` and add after username `:password`

before : `https://username@bitbucket.org/repo.git`

afetr : `https://username:password@bitbucket.org/repo.git`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was just a wrong password for bitbucket entered into the prompt dialog. When I entered the correct password, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio you might want to try enabling "Use credential helper".

Steps:

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Version control -> Git
2. Find "Use credential helper" option (mostly at bottom)
3. Enable this option by marking the checkbox before the option

Answer (score -2):

I got this issue when I upgraded from Windows 7 to 8 and settings messed up for me too. I had to regenerate private and public keys, and change my TortoiseGIT to use plink, instead of SSH.exe

I wrote step by step instructions at http://techblog.saurabhkumar.com/2015/09/using-tortoisegit-on-windows-with.html

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to your own site. Instead, put the essential information in your answer itself. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235)

Comment: Link is dead, by the way.

Answer (score -2):

For Bitbucket If you are ok for the repo to be public you can just uncheck the "This is a private repository" checkbox in repo settings. Now a simple git clone should work.