# Cannot push to Bitbucket via https anymore: git returns fatal error

Tags: git, bitbucket

I recently reinstalled windows and got the latest version of git. I created a new repo on Bitbucket and ran

```
git remote add origin https://MYUSERNAME@bitbucket.org/MYUSERNAME/test.git
```

then I ran

```
git push -u origin --all
```

however this gave me the error

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://MYUSERNAME@bitbucket.org': No such
file or directory
```

before I would just get a prompt asking me for my username and password, and the push worked fine. I've tried reverting to Git 1.7.11 but this didn't do anything.

Comment: We had this question a lot in the past few days—unfortunately without a clear solution. Can you try removing the remote again using `git remote remove origin` and then readding it?

Comment: @poke still the same error, I have managed to push by adding this as origin `https://MYUSERNAME:MYPASSWORD@bitbucket.org/MYUSERNAME/test.git` but this doesnt help for cloning

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue, I just installed version 1.8.5.2-preview20131230. Can you please post which version you installed first? Thanks

Comment: This is due to a bug in release 1.8.5.2 as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882088/cant-push-after-git-update.

Comment: Please go to the link a follow the steps: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/44027171/5297884](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44027171/5297884)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to change the protocol from HTTPS to GIT.

Followed the instructions to setup SSH here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

(easy from the GitBash console, ***you don't need to install SSH or nothing***, all comes with Git)

After you completed the SSH setup, just re-add the remote with the git@bitbucket.... url and you are done.

Hope this helps.

*I have installed Git version 1.8.5.2-preview20131230*

Answer (score 15):

I solved this by adding my password in the url.

Instead of:

```
git remote add origin https://MYUSERNAME@bitbucket.org/MYUSERNAME/test.git
```

I used:

```
git remote add origin https://MYUSERNAME:PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/MYUSERNAME/test.git
```

Comment: That's kinda intimidating. Won't a guy with a net wire sweeper see your password as you type it along with the username and the target?

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when updated git to 1.8.5.2.
When I rolled git to version 1.7.10 (initial version), the error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

As I really needed to use HTTPS instead of SSH (proxy limitations), I've solved it by setting the remote `push url` to the HTTPS url as follow:

`git remote set-url --push origin https://MYUSERNAME@bitbucket.org/MYUSERNAME/test.git`

*git version 1.9.5*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Installing Git 1.9.0 solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding my ssh key to the repository and using the ssh url

Answer (score 0):

If you experience this issue using GitExtensions then this might help you:

> GitExt -> Tools -> Settings -> SSH -> Configure Git credential helper -> Suggest

That populated the command field with:

```
!"C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\GitCredentialWinStore\git-credential-winstore.exe"
```