# Cannot push to Bitbucket after installing git-lfs

Tags: git, authentication, bitbucket, git-lfs

After installing `git lfs`, git keeps asking for my password when trying to execute:

```
git push origin master
```

It's as if `git` was stuck in an infinite loop: No error message, nothing, but I am being prompted for my password over and over again. The repo was cloned over HTTPS.

The closest question seems to be:

[Cannot push to Bitbucket via https anymore: git returns fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20928681/341970)

According to the answers to that question my options are:

- Use SSH, *or*
- add my password to the URL.

(The other answers concerning the version of git don't count: I am using git 2.7.4 with git-lfs/2.1.1 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.8.1)   so it's not that my git is too old.)

Is there any other alternative to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, caching the password resolved the issue:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

(Although I am not sure it is not a bug in git or in git-lfs.)

I have found this answer at [git lfs stuck in push from last week [FIXED]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/010ee389-8757-49dd-ae21-66aa70b6374c/git-lfs-stuck-in-push-from-last-week-fixed?forum=TFService), and not here on Stackoverflow, and that is why I am posting it here in a Q&A-style.