# Cannot Push to Master

Tags: git, github

I can't figure out the workflow on this. I keep getting the following error when trying to push to my repository:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
```

I've set up the repository on Github, then I `git clone`d it.

Locally it's fine. I made some changes to the `README.md` file. Then, I `git add -A`d it, so the changes are ready. I then `git commit -m '...'`d it, and the commit is ready.

I set up the remote using:

```
git remote add Midlife https://github.com/cireficc/Midlife.git
```

So now I should be able to `git push Midlife master` because the commit is ready to go. But no, I run into the 'could not read Username' error.

I've set up the local commit info using

```
git config --global user.name "<my name>"
git config --global user.email "<my email>"
```

so I really don't know what's wrong.

It doesn't ask me for credentials but just gives me the error message quoted above, so I'm kind of lost.

---

<sup>*Edit:* This question is also a duplicate of: [[dup1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20871549/1761499) -- [[dup2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20882088/1761499) -- [[dup3]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20923193/1761499)</sup>

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: `Midlife hhtps://github.com/cireficc/Midlife.git (fetch)`, `Midlife hhtps://github.com/cireficc/Midlife.git (push)`.

Comment: Did you copy-and-paste that? The URL doesn’t match what you have in the question.

Comment: That was just 2 coincidental typos. I uninstalled version 1.8.5.2 and installed the next version down, 1.8.4.something, and it works fine now. It's a bug in the most recent version, something I couldn't predict and that I couldn't find by search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug in current *Git for Windows* (version 1.8.5.2 aka `Git-1.8.5.2-preview20131230`).

You can see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/msysgit/s4dB8Nv9V4c/55-cGPdPYmAJ) for the discussion and instructions to fix it.

If a newer Git for Windows has been released, try installing that and see if it fixes the issue. If it doesn't please report it to the developers, and use an older version, the fix suggested in that thread, or an SSH remote instead.

**Edit**: As more users are still running into this problem, I have created an [unofficial fix release 1.8.5.4](https://github.com/nevik/git/releases/tag/v1.8.5.4.msysgit.nevik.0) (`Git-1.8.5.4-nevik20140208`) which includes the fix for this bug presented in the mailinglist thread linked above. As of now (2014-02-09), there's no new official *Git for Windows* reease yet, so this should serve until there is one.

Comment: That's what it seems to be. What a nightmare. I've been trying to fix this for 2 hours...

Comment: I'm most surprised at the fact that a new release has not been made. This issue is quite common (dunno if it appears for everyone), and Git 1.8.5.3 has been out for a while now.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that their last actual release was over a month ago. With such a (what I imagine to be) large-scale-impact bug, a new release should have been made, even if only to fix that single problem. It's unfortunate that they advertise the latest release as 'stable', when this is the first time I've used this version and couldn't even push 1 file. I'm sure the devs will get around to a new release soon :P

Comment: As a workaround, I suspect the SSH URL should work (but of course you’ll have to setup keys).

Comment: @ChrisCirefice I've created an unofficial fix release, as more users are still having this problem. If you've already applied the fix yourself, this might be a bit late. But feel free to spread the word if you know anyone else who is having this problem. (Link is added to my answer)